# Verify a hash generated with php crypt() in NodeJS?

Tags: php, node.js, authentication, cryptography, openssl

I have a PHP 5.3 webserver with the Lithium framework running on it.

I have password hashes generated with `CRYPT_BLOWFISH` :

```
public static function hash($password, $salt = null) {
    return crypt($password, $salt ?: static::salt());
}
```

They get checked with this :

```
public static function check($password, $hash) {
    return String::compare(crypt($password, $hash), $hash);
}
```

I'm looking for the `NodeJS` script that would enable me to both check and generate similar hashes :

I've tried this so far (check for now) :

```
var c = crypto.createCipher('bf-cfb', password);
var res = c.update(hash);
res += c.final('utf8');
```

Where (not exact vars, but looks like this) :

```
var hash = '$2a$10$nA5CV2XWJGn0cbKxSHU3GOp29ypHNVJDglJ0iNFx2zFkfy3mrsRZK'; // from php
var salt = '$2a$10$nku2zgjB65zLdcVC1BIhG.'; // from php too
var password = 'passwordInClearTextToCheck'; // correct password to check
```

Is it possible to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Crypt() function uses different algorithm, this is not raw Blowfish encryption/decryption.
Since there is no Crypt() implementation for node.js yet, I would recommend to hash password + salt with SHA1/SHA256/whatever else.